# Data binding with the function toString("some string")

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-resources, android-databinding

I want to show creation date of a note. I'm using data binding , I need to use toString function to have a formatted date string, but toString function takes a string as argument. Here is the code:

```
<data>
        <import type="com.example.path.myproject.model.Note"/>
        <variable
            name="noteViewModel"
            type="com.example.path.myproject.note.NoteViewModel" />
</data>

        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/createdDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@{noteViewModel.note.createDate.toString("dd/mm/yyyy")}"
        />
```

But I have an error, because I can't use double quotes inside there. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that attribute in single quotes, and then you can use double quotes inside it.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createdDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text='@{noteViewModel.note.createDate.toString("dd/mm/yyyy")}'
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an string in strings value file then pass value to that string.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/createdDate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text='@{@string/dateString(noteViewModel.note.createDate("dd/mm/yyyy"))}'/>
```